# Why do some of these definitions work, and the other fails?

Tags: haskell, types

For some reason, definitions f3 and f6 work, while f4 does not

```
f3 :: Num a => a -> a -> a -> a -> a
f3 = undefined

f4 :: String a => a -> a -> a -> a -> a
f4 = undefined

f6 :: [Char] -> [Char] -> [Char] -> [Char] -> [Char]
f6 = undefined
```

The error message is `Expected kind ‘* -> Constraint’, but ‘String’ has kind ‘*’`, which I have googled but did not manage to understand

Do note the similarity between f3 and f4. Also, I am a beginner, if that is relevant to the possible explanations.

Thanks!

Comment: `String` is *not* a typeclass, `Num` is. A typeclass is basically a *group* of types, so `Num a` is a constraint: the costraint is satisfied if `a` is a *member* of the `Num` typeclass. `String` on the other hand is a type.

Comment: The difference is that `Num` is a typeclass, while `String` is a type.

Comment: You mean `f4 :: String -> String -> String -> String -> String`.

Comment: ...or `f4'' :: String ~ a => a -> a -> a -> a -> a`. Notice the `~`, which is a built-in “equality type class”, as it were, i.e. `(String~)` is the class of types equal to `String` (which thus includes _only_ `String`). Not really a type class, but it can be used like one. This requires `-XTypeFamilies`, which is a harmless extension, still I wouldn't necessarily recommend it over the simple `String -> String -> ...`.

Comment: Haskell values "have types". What is a type of `"123"`? It's `String`. What kind of a type is `String`? it's a kind of a type that Haskell values have. What is a type of `1`? It is `Num a => a`, i.e. some type that belongs to the `Num` typeclass. What is `Num`? it is kind of a type, but not such as Haskell values have; it is a `Constraint` on a type which a Haskell value has. e.g. `Int` satisfies `Num Int`. Notice `Num` expects a type as an argument. That's what's meant by *" `Num`'s kind is `* -> Constraint`"*, because `*` is a kind of types that Haskell values have. Like `Int`. Or `String`.

Comment: i.e. `Num` is a group of types, to which some given concrete type might or might not belong; `String` is one, concrete type; `Int` is also a concrete type; `Integer` is another. both `Int` and `Integer` belong to `Num`, String doesn't. No type belongs to `String` -- none *can*; asking so is an ill-posed question, because `String` is not a type class. It is a concrete type ("of kind" `*`). put another way, `String`'s "kind" is not `* -> Constraint`, it's `*`.